# Python3, Selenium, BeautifulSoup4 stack does not load further information from site

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to get some information from a site over here in Germany. As this site loads more content by clicking on a down arrow at the bottom of the site, i thought i should use `selenium` to achieve the loading process. After that, the script should get the needed information via BeautifulSoup and fetch it to a CSV file.

Unfortunately my script seems to not click on the desired button, so I only receive the first part of information.

My code looks as follows:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


with open('shoop.csv','w', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
    csv_writer.writerow(['Headline', 'Cashback'])
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.shoop.de/stoebern/haus_technik/3/popular/')
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('icon-down_open_big').click()
    r = driver.page_source

    driver.quit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
    for advertiser in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'merchant_item'}):    
        headline = advertiser.find('h3', {'class':'merchant_name'}).text
        cashback = advertiser.find('span', {'class':'rates_number'}).text
        liste = ([headline, cashback])
        print(liste)
        csv_writer.writerow(liste)
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Thx Leva, that saved my day. With a bit of extra sleep time in my code the export to csv works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of JavaScript on that site. Perhaps the arrow only appears when the user scrolls down to a certain extent. When I added the scrolling to your code, the arrow was pressed successfully

Scrolling a page in Selenium is done by executing a script:

```
# Whenever you want to press the arrow, scroll down with this line
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('icon-down_open_big').click()
```